# What's the correct Path of a file in an Intellij Idea project?

Tags: java, file, gradle, intellij-idea, path

this is my first time asking, so I hope I'll do it correctly.

I'm working on a Gradle project in Intellij Idea, which consists of several modules. In one module, whose name is "utilities", there's a directory "src" which has 2 other directories: main and test. In the test directory there are: /java -> packageName -> TestClass and a file "name.txt". I need to use this file in a test class, but I'm unable to select the correct Pat.

The project has a directory \project\project[package]\utilities\src\test\resources\file.txt

and inside the test directory there's another directory called \java\[package]\TestClass which uses the file. I tries using Path.of("pathSuggestedByIntellij") but it didn't work.

If I use the Path of my pc (C:\users...) then it works; if i use the path suggested by Intellij, obtained right clicking on the name.txt file and then using "copy Path/reference..." it doesn't work, in any way: I tried the absolute path, path from content root, path from source root... But nothing seems working. Do you have any suggestions? Thanks to everyone :D

Comment: Can you update the question with some code of what you've tried so far?

Comment: If it's being used as a resource (not being written to) then it should be in a resource directory at the package root (level with your 'packageName') and be accessed with `InputStream in = TestClass.class.getResourceAsStream("/x.txt");`

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I solved using Path.of("src\\test\\resources\\file.txt"). Thanks to everyone who tried to help :D